# Setting validationGroup on postback in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have several server controls like textbox, dropdowns in my ASP.net Page. I have requredfieldvalidators for all the above fields with errorMessage="Required".

I have a button called btnSave.

For all the requiredfieldValidators, I have a validationGroup="save" and I have the same for the btnSave.

Now for one of the dropdowns, ddlResult if the value is 299 I don't want the requirefieldvalidator to work.

In the code behind for the selectedIndexChange of ddlResult I have something like this

```
protected void ddResult_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ddResult.SelectedValue != "399")
            {
                rfv1.ValidationGroup = "save";
            }
            else
            {
                rfv1.ValidationGroup = "";
            }
        }
```

Inspite of doing this the requiredfieldvalidator is getting fired. The requiredfieldvalidator.

Any thoughts??

Comment: So your DDL is set to AutoPostBack=true, correct? Also I didn't get one thing, if value is 299, something is selected? So which RFV are you pointing to? rfv1 is for some other control or hooked up to DDL?

Comment: You want to hide validation only from your dropdown  or all Validators ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CauseValidation` property of the `DropDownList` to *false*.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `InitialValue` property value of the `RequiredFieldValidator` control to the value that you want to get ingnored. In your case this value is *299* (Or *399*).